# Anaconda docker user permissions

Tags: docker, kubernetes, anaconda, apache-zeppelin

I'm struggling with some issue related with container user permissions.

I've created an image from [this dockerfile](https://github.com/apache/zeppelin/blob/master/scripts/docker/zeppelin/bin/Dockerfile).

As you can see, at [line 128](https://github.com/apache/zeppelin/blob/master/scripts/docker/zeppelin/bin/Dockerfile#L128) it's changing to `USER 1000`.

I'm trying to play with anaconda using this command:

```
$ conda install pandas 
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed

NotWritableError: The current user does not have write permissions to a required path.
  path: /opt/conda/pkgs/cache/9e0f62c3.json
  uid: 1000
  gid: 0

If you feel that permissions on this path are set incorrectly, you can manually
change them by executing

  $ sudo chown 1000:0 /opt/conda/pkgs/cache/9e0f62c3.json

In general, it's not advisable to use 'sudo conda'.
```

Any ideas about how to deal with that issue?

Comment: Is the conda executable itself changing the user id, perhaps via set-user-id? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58168/how-does-the-set-user-id-mechanism-work-in-unix

Answer (score 2):

If you want to extend the Dockerfile change the user back to root `USER 0` before installing anything and afterwards back to an unprivileged one `USER 1000`. If you are running the container or execing into it add `--user 0` to your command `docker run --user 0 zeppelin`.